# Assess each row of a factor in R

Tags: r

I have a factor with 1000 rows and 848 levels (i.e. some rows are empty). For each row, I want to count the number of elements (i.e., one element = 1, 2 elements = 2, empty row = 0, etc.). A simpler way to describe it is: I want to convert a factor into a data.frame, but I want to change the data type from factor to numeric and keep the values in each row.

```
v.m.two <- Output[,1]
v.m.two <- data.frame(v.m.two)
class(v.m.two)
[1] data.frame
class(v.m.two[1,]
[1] factor
dim(v.m.two)
[1] 1000 1
v.m.two[1,]
[1] 848 Levels: 0 1000 1002, 4875, 4082, 1952 1015, 2570, 3524 1017 1020, 1576 ... 983, 4381,
2256, 4361, 4271
```

Any suggestions?

```
           v.m.two
1       2633, 4868
2        126, 4860
3                0
4        122, 4762
5             4256
6 2933, 2892, 2389
```

Basically, I want to count the values in each row (e.g., row 1 is 2, row 2 is 2, row 3 is 0, etc.).

Comment: Can you show a few lines of `v.m.two`? You also might want to use `v.m.two <- data.frame(v.m.two, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`

Comment: What do you mean by "count the number of elements"? Each row only has a single value. Do you just want `as.numeric(as.character(v.m.two[, 1]))`?

Comment: Hey Richard, I made the edits in the original post.
I've already tried that, but it's not working the way it was intended. I'm unsure why >.>

Comment: Ok, maybe you want `sapply(strsplit(as.character(v.m.two[, 1]), ','), length)`

Comment: Hey jbaums, since the data type is a factor, you're correct in that each row contains a single value. But within each row, there contains a list of elements separated by a "," and I want to count these values.

Comment: By the way, if you want people to know that you've mentioned them in a comment, then you need to use, e.g. @jbaums (unless it's their post, in which case they get notified of all comments).

Comment: @jbaums, thanks for the two advice! Your code almost worked, except that the 0's are considered as numbers, instead of an empty row.

Comment: @user2105555  What is the result you really wanted?  DO you want a data.frame with `ncol` equal to the maximum number of element in each row of the original dataset `v.m.two` or just a vector of values ?

Comment: @akrun The result I really wanted is the output of a vector of values from running a simulation of 1000 iterations, then use the values to plot onto a graph. haha. But the entire time I was stuck on manipulating the data types to perform the calculations I wanted. I figured everything else out but not the solution to the novice question as per the original post. >.<

Comment: @user2105555 Thanks and sorry I misunderstood while reading the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1 Converting factor to numeric**

- If you want to convert the `factor` columns to `numeric` and want to have separate columns based on the number of elements in each row.

  ```
   library(splitstackshape)
   res <- cSplit(v.m.two, 'v.m.two', sep=",")
   res
   #    v.m.two_1 v.m.two_2 v.m.two_3
   #1:      2633      4868        NA
   #2:       126      4860        NA
   #3:         0        NA        NA
   #4:       122      4762        NA
   #5:      4256        NA        NA
   #6:      2933      2892      2389

    str(res)
    #Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':   6 obs. of  3 variables:
    #$ v.m.two_1: int  2633 126 0 122 4256 2933
    # $ v.m.two_2: int  4868 4860 NA 4762 NA 2892
    #$ v.m.two_3: int  NA NA NA NA NA 2389
  ```
- If you need a `vector`, you could use `stri_split` from `stringi`

  ```
    library(stringi)
    as.numeric(unlist(stri_split(v.m.two[,1], regex=",")))
    #[1] 2633 4868  126 4860    0  122 4762 4256 2933 2892 2389
  ```

**2. Counting values in row**

- For counting the values in each row of `v.m.two`, you could either count from the `res` above or from `v.m.two`.  In the first option, we are counting the number of `NAs` in each row of `res` and then multiplying with the logical index derived from whether the first column of `v.m.two` is `0` or not. The `TRUE` values i.e. `!=0` will get the `count` while the `FALSE` will coerce to `0` ie. `0 * value=0`

  ```
    (v.m.two[,1]!=0)*(rowSums(!is.na(res)))
    #[1] 2 2 0 2 1 3
  ```
- You could use `stri_count` from `stringi` which would be fast ([counting occurrence of particular letter in vector of words in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680916/counting-occurrence-of-particular-letter-in-vector-of-words-in-r/26680969#26680969)). Here as above, you can either use the `arithmetic` i.e. multiplying or could use `ifelse`.  The `regex` can be based on `digits` or `,`.  If you are using `,`, then make sure to add `1`.

  ```
    ifelse(v.m.two[,1]=0, stri_count(v.m.two[,1], regex="\\d+"), 0)
    # [1] 2 2 0 2 1 3
    #Or

    (v.m.two[,1]!=0) *stri_count(v.m.two[,1], regex="\\d+")
    #[1] 2 2 0 2 1 3
    #Or   
    (v.m.two[,1]!=0) *(stri_count(v.m.two[,1], regex=",") +1)
    #[1] 2 2 0 2 1 3
  ```
- Another option to count would be to use `gsub` and `nchar` from `base R`.

  ```
    (v.m.two[,1]!=0) *( nchar(gsub("[^,]", "", v.m.two[,1]))+1)
    #[1] 2 2 0 2 1 3
  ```

#### data

```
v.m.two <- structure(list(v.m.two = structure(c(4L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 6L, 5L), 
.Label = c("0", "122, 4762", "126, 4860", "2633, 4868", "2933, 2892, 2389",
 "4256"), class = "factor")), .Names = "v.m.two", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 1):

You have erroneous commas which is causing the factors.  Try `scan`

```
scan(text=with(v.m.two, levels(v.m.two)[v.m.two]), sep=",", what=integer())
# Read 11 items
# [1] 2633 4868  126 4860    0  122 4762 4256 2933 2892 2389
```

And to count the lengths and convert to numeric, you can also use `strsplit`

```
s <- strsplit(as.character(v.m.two[[1]]), ", ")
vapply(s, length, integer(1L)) ## row 3 is actually 1 if there's a zero there
# [1] 2 2 1 2 1 3
as.numeric(do.call(c, s))
# [1] 2633 4868  126 4860    0  122 4762 4256 2933 2892 2389
```

Comment: I received this error:
Error in scan(file, what, nmax, sep, dec, quote, skip, nlines, na.strings,  :scan() expected 'an integer', got '2633,'

Comment: Because I used spaces and not commas, about to fix