# Column counting in R. Just started using it for GWAS and I am lost

Tags: r, regex, sorting, counting

Can anyone help me working out how to count the number of instances of a character in a cell per row? I have a file with 10 million snps that I want to sort.

```
Direction
?????+-+-
?+-+-????
?-+-+??-+
```

Above is an example of one of many columns that I have. What I want to do is count the number of "?" characters in each row individually and add a new column with that count as a numerical value.

I'm a total beginner thrown in the deep end with this so any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you really have a format like this? SNPs are usually 0s, 1s, 2s or NAs..

Comment: Please read [How to make a great reproducible example in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: Try `nchar(gsub("[^\\?]", "", Direction))`

Comment: This is just one of the columns, the data indicates whether or not a particular SNP was found in a study (the datatable has 15 studies in it) and the direction of its effect.

So it might look like

    Direction
    ???-++++--???--

I am trying to find a way to count the "?" so I know how many studies that particular SNP was found in. At the moment the direction doesn't matter.

Comment: @juan The escape character is not necessary here, `"[^?]"` is sufficient.

Comment: @Imo, Good to know!

Answer (score 1):

Two answers for you

```
a <- data.frame(direction = c("?????+-+-", "?+-+-????","?-+-+??-+"),  
 stringAsFactors = F)
a$return <- lengths(regmatches(a$direction, gregexpr("\\?", a$direction)))
```

or as per comments

```
a$return <- nchar(gsub("[^?]", "", a$direction))
```

Both return

```
'data.frame':   3 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ direction: chr  "?????+-+-" "?+-+-????" "?-+-+??-+"
 $ return   : int  5 5 3
```

There are tons of ways to do this depends on what you're looking for.

## Update

While it may not be base R, the packages in the [tidyverse](http://tidyverse.org/) are useful for data wrangling and can be used to string together a few calls easily.

```
install.packages("dplyr")
library(dplyr)
df <- data.frame(Direction = c("???????????-?", "???????????+?", "???????????+?", "???????????-?"), stringsAsFactors = F)
df %>% 
  mutate(qmark = nchar(gsub("[^?]", "", Direction)),
         pos = nchar(gsub("[^+]", "", Direction)),
         neg = nchar(gsub("[^-]", "", Direction)),
         qminus = qmark-(pos+neg),
         total = nchar(Direction))  


      Direction qmark pos neg qminus total
1 ???????????-?    12   0   1     11    13
2 ???????????+?    12   1   0     11    13
3 ???????????+?    12   1   0     11    13
4 ???????????-?    12   0   1     11    13
```

If your dataset is 10 million lines long however, you might want to use `stringi` based on some benchmark [testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26680916/counting-occurrence-of-particular-letter-in-vector-of-words-in-r).

```
install.packages("stringi")
library(stringi)
df %>% 
  mutate(qmark = stri_count(Direction, fixed = "?"),
         pos = stri_count(Direction, fixed = "+"),
         neg = stri_count(Direction, fixed = "-"), 
         qminus = qmark-(pos+neg))
```

Comment: I don't know if I'm not asking the right questions or don't know enough about R to format things properly but non of the suggestions are working. Neither doing what I wanted or doing what you say they will do.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: As said in the comments, if you could provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) the answer will work for *your* data.  I made a `data.frame` to provide a solution but your data may have a different structure and thus R will handle it differently.

Comment: okay I have got somewhere using "top$DirectionCount = nchar(gsub("[^\\?]", "", top$Direction))"

Now I have the "?" in a new column of my table! Great stuff.

Comment: Now I'd like to make a new column with that "?" count minus the count of + and - characters in the column. 

Is that also possible?

Comment: Apologies if this is frustrating or ridiculously basic.

Comment: Read through the [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) post, produce a sample of your data, and state exactly what you need.  No one wants to answer the wrong question even if it's for fake internet points, and being new to R understanding data structure is essential.

Comment: Okay I will do that. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Okay I will do that. Thanks for the advice.

Just as an update, I managed to do what I wanted probably in the most roundabout way possible.

> top$DirectionCount = nchar(gsub("[^\\?]", "", top$Direction))
> top$DirectionCountneg = nchar(gsub("[^\\-]", "", top$Direction))
> top$DirectionCountpos = nchar(gsub("[^\\+]", "", top$Direction))

To add 3 columns.

Then,

Sequentially took the values for "-" and "+" from the count for "?".

I think I will look for a more elegant solution.

Comment: I'm a recent grad that got into data work in in college, so I understand needing to get some R work done even if it's over your head.  There are some great intro resources like [r for data science](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/), or if you want specifically [(meta)genomics](http://evomics.org/learning/programming/introduction-to-r/) people have written some tutorials because it's tough.  Keep scripting and it will become easier.  Also, use Ctrl+K or the ` symbols around code so it's easy to read.

Comment: What is the output from running `str(your data)`?

Comment: It outputs a list of the 26 column headers or variables with examples of the observed values in each column or variable. Oh and if the value is a character, number, integer etc

Comment: can you paste it here or `dput(head(your data))`?  There are issues with string matching if that information isn't known from your question.

Comment: ' $ Freq1              : num  0.9889 0.012 0.0104 0.9887 0.9887 ...
 $ FreqSE             : num  0 0 0 0 0.0004 0 0 0 0 0.0012 ...
 $ MinFreq            : num  0.9889 0.012 0.0104 0.9887 0.9869 ...
 $ MaxFreq            : num  0.9889 0.012 0.0104 0.9887 0.9895 ...
 $ Effect             : num  -0.286 0.277 0.293 -0.292 -0.238 ...
 $ StdErr             : num  0.0353 0.0347 0.037 0.039 0.0332 ...
 $ P.value            : num  5.06e-16 1.43e-15 2.20e-15 6.83e-14 6.98e-13 ...
 $ Direction          : chr  "???????????-?" "???????????+?" "???????????+?" "???????????-?" ...'